# PostgreSql INSERT FROM SELECT RETURNING ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, postgresql-9.2

In PostgreSql 9.2.4 I have two tables: `user (id, login, password, name)` and `dealer (id, user_id)`.

And I want to insert into both tables returning id of created dealer.

Currently I'm doing it with two queries:

```
WITH rows AS (
    INSERT INTO "user"
        (login, password, name)
    VALUES
        ('dealer1', 'jygbjybk', 'Dealer 1')
    RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO dealer (user_id)
    SELECT id
    FROM rows;
SELECT currval('dealer_id_seq');
```

But can I implement this with a single `INSERT` query using `RETURNING` statement?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You just need to add a `RETURNING id` to your `INSERT ... SELECT`:

```
WITH rows AS (...)
INSERT INTO dealer (user_id)
    SELECT id
    FROM rows
    RETURNING id;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/75008/1

Answer (score 23):

For my purposes, I needed it in a variable so I did this:

```
INSERT INTO dealer (user_id)
    SELECT id
    FROM rows
    RETURNING id INTO l_dealerid;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed thank you