# PostgreSQL Transaction in one Trip

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

In my very unsophisticated PostgreSQL v8.4.13 database with tables `A` and `B`, column `A.a`, is a `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` that is `FOREIGN KEY`ed to `B.a`. There are other columns in both tables. `a` is *not* `UNIQUE` in `B`.

In the confines of one transaction I would like to add one row to `A` and a corresponding row to `B`.

I'm scripting with the PHP PDO for PGL.

Is it possible to do such a thing in one round trip?

Is it possible to do similarly with multiple rows to `B` in one round trip?

Comment: Absolutely, you have to opt-out of auto commit w/ [manual mode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php).

Comment: When you say "one round trip", do you mean one exec call (a single query)?

Comment: I mean one message to the DB from the script with one return value of whatever. I don't know enough about the connection to know how to state it any better than this.

Comment: Just separate the queries with a `;` in the sql string argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `INSERT ... RETURNING` statement to retrieve the newly-generated `SERIAL` value for `A.a`, and you can use a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to pack both `INSERT`s into the same statement:

```
WITH Inserted AS (
  INSERT INTO A (data)
  VALUES ('data')
  RETURNING A.a
)
INSERT INTO B (a, data)
SELECT Inserted.a, 'more data'
FROM Inserted;
```

If you want to insert multiple records into `B`, you can fill out the remaining fields in a `VALUES` expression, and join in the new `A.a` value for the `INSERT`:

```
WITH Inserted (a) AS (
  INSERT INTO A (data)
  VALUES ('data')
  RETURNING A.a
),
BValues (data) AS (
  VALUES
    ('data1'),
    ('data2'),
    ('data3')
)
INSERT INTO B (a, data)
SELECT Inserted.a, BValues.data
FROM Inserted CROSS JOIN BValues;
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm curious to know if this is executed as a transaction without my explicitly doing so.

Comment: @QED: If you haven't explicitly started a transaction, Postgres will begin and commit one for each statement (and a CTE counts as a single statement, despite the multiple sub-expressions). Many client libraries will override this behaviour by starting their own transactions behind the scenes, though from what I can tell, PDO's default behaviour seems to be in line with Postgres'.

Comment: Is it possible to do insert multiple rows in `B` with one round trip?

Answer (score -1):

As long as the updates are to the same DB, you can have multiple executions per transaction:

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$dbh->exec("UPDATE A SET last = 'hi'");
$dbh->exec("UPDATE B SET name = 'Rafael'");
/* MULTIPLE EXECS HERE */
$dbh->commit();
```

Comment: Why am I dropping table `A`?

Comment: That is an example of the statements you would run, to have both in *one* transaction. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: My answer did not steer you wrong, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105138/tips-on-sending-multiple-query-with-postgresql). [using multiple transactions in one function call is not recommended.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php), I am not sure why you downvoted me.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I think someone else did that because he knew the data in `A` is very important to me.

Comment: The `DROP` statement was an example of multiple statements in one transaction. Surely, you wouldn't copy and paste this code and run it blindly...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd